# Align flexbox with flex-direction:column to vertical center

Tags: css, flexbox

How to align items to vertical center?

I am using both `flex-direction: column;` and `align-items: center;`.

```css
.box{
border: 1px solid red;
width: 100%;
height: 180px;

display: -webkit-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;

-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
-webkit-box-direction: normal;
-ms-flex-direction: column;
flex-direction: column;

-webkit-box-align: center;
-ms-flex-align: center;
align-items: center;
}

.item{
width: 20%;
border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need to align vertically also,. inside the red border

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hope This Will Work For You!

```css
.box{
     border: 1px solid red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    /* -webkit-box-orient: vertical; */
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

}
.item{
  width: 20%;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great Answer...

Answer (score 3):

Add `justify-content: center;` to `.box`

```css
.box{
border: 1px solid red;
width: 100%;
height: 180px;

display: -webkit-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;

-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
-webkit-box-direction: normal;
-ms-flex-direction: column;
flex-direction: column;

-webkit-box-align: center;
-ms-flex-align: center;
align-items: center;

  justify-content: center;
}

.item{
width: 20%;
border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding

```
justify-content: center
```

to .box should be ok.